# Difference between application/vnd.xls and application/vnd.ms-excel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

In my c#.NET MVC application you can download an excel file (with the Nuget EPPlus). To send the file to user I set content type as it follows:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
```

What is the difference with:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: Neither are correct for XLSX files... See the linked question for the correct values.

Comment: I don't think "application/vnd.xls" has ever been the correct value.  Your 2nd option is correct for the older XLS format.

Comment: Thank you for the answers,  "application/vnd.xls" is working but the format was kind of weird so I was wondering

Comment: Try using System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(yourFileName) to get MIME types - much better than hard-coding strings.

Comment: @Pete This should be the answer